# How can I tell whether the current page has a screen wakelock?

Tags: html, chromium, web-wake-lock

In testing an application that uses the [`navigator.wakeLock.request`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WakeLock/request) API, I'd like to be able to check that the wakelock is or is not held at appropriate times. I can put the phone down and wait to see if the screen turns off, but I don't see a way for Chrome's or Edge's DevTools to just tell me. Is there such a way?

As mentioned in https://github.com/w3c/screen-wake-lock/issues/247, the page doesn't get an accurate impression of the wakelock state either, so the page can't just display it in a debug mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will get an error from `navigator.wakeLock.request()` if the wake lock was denied for reasons like permissions. The GitHub issue refers to wake locks being denied due to operating system policy (such as "battery saver" modes) and I am not aware of any system which actually does this.

Nevertheless showing wake lock state seems like a reasonable feature request for DevTools.

Comment: +1 to what Reilly said. I have filed a [feature request](https://crbug.com/1159361) for DevTools to track this.